# GWT Composite that wraps a DockLayoutpanel - Composite or ResizeComposite?

Tags: gwt

When I implement a custom widget, which wraps a DockLayoutPanel, should I let it extend `Composite` or `ResizeComposite`?

The docs say:

> When creating a custom Composite widget that wrap a widget that implements RequiresResize, you should use ResizeComposite as its base class. This subclass of Composite automatically propagates resize events to its wrapped widget.

But in most examples I saw, the custom widget extended `Composite`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `DockLayoutPanel` implements `RequiresResize` you should use a `ResizeComposite`. Looking at the [`ResizeComposite` source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ResizeComposite.java&q=ResizeComposite.java%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) one sees that the only change it makes to `Composite` is the addition of the `onResize()` method.